# How to get the bundle hash or tail transaction hash by using the prepare_transfer() and send_trytes methods?

Tags: tangle, pyota, hornet, python

I am sending data to my hornet private tangle in Python. I wanted to do separate api calls to prepare the transaction and publish the transaction. So, I used api.prepare_transfer() and api.send_trytes() to do the before mentioned tasks. The code is working properly but I am not able to get the bundle hash or tail transaction hash.
Can someone please help me?